# Android Bluetooth connection parameter

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I very long Looking for but not found a answer, hot to change bluetooth connection parameter (**Connection Interval**, **Slave Latency**, **Supervision Timeout**) on Android (master) device. Must importent for me is Supervision Timeout becouse on android by defaut is 20 seconds and i need lessen, i find `CONNECTION_PRIORITY_BALANCED`, `CONNECTION_PRIORITY_HIGH` and `CONNECTION_PRIORITY_LOW_POWER` but they dont change Supervision Timeout time,

or impossible to change connection parameter from Android (master)?
Please help me.
Thanks in advence.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you are only allowed to do whatever API allows you. In most cases, mobile OS APIs do not allow you to do low level settings for the purpose of user friendly experience. Imagine you developed an app which uses connection parameters that drains battery... Then the user of your application would most probably complain about the OS provider or the OEM. This is not wanted and should be prevented. However, if you want to do low level changes for experimental reasons (research etc.), I would recommend you to download the Android API source code, do the changes and insert the custom ANdroid API to your phone (you need to root your phone).

Here is the related part from the source code in `BluetoothGatt.class` related to your request:

```
    public boolean requestConnectionPriority(int connectionPriority) {
    if (connectionPriority < CONNECTION_PRIORITY_BALANCED ||
        connectionPriority > CONNECTION_PRIORITY_LOW_POWER) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("connectionPriority not within valid range");
    }

    if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "requestConnectionPriority() - params: " + connectionPriority);
    if (mService == null || mClientIf == 0) return false;

    try {
        mService.connectionParameterUpdate(mClientIf, mDevice.getAddress(), connectionPriority);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.e(TAG,"",e);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I would look for the implementation of `BluetoothGattService#connectionParameterUpdate`.

Comment: good but then how to find out when bluetooth le device is disconnected,in less than 20 seconds ? example out of range or power off ? because at now i need to wait 20 seconds when connection state is changing

Comment: well I am just assuming but my assumptions can be a good starting point for you. there must be a variable representing supervision timeout in the firmware code or android source code. you can modify this variable and hardcode the value you want. i don't think it is easy but i think it is not impossible.

Comment: but i don't find nowhere in android code ir i change timeout time in bluetooth module RN4020(slave) when i connected with Android (master) and master set timeout time again in 20 seconds,i dont have idea how to less than... and dont find any variables with represent timeout time....

Comment: Check this website which instructs how to download android source code: [link](https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html). It is very normal that Android sets the value back because according to Bluetooth Spec when master (phone) sends a connection update request, the slave should accept it. (check Bluetooth 4.0 spec for more information)